# TypeScript error: Reserved word 'this' used as name

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webstorm, keyword

I am trying to get [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts) Node.js TypeScript definition to work, but WebStorm gives me a big list of errors with all the same message:

> Reserved word 'this' used as name. This inspection
>   reports on any uses of JavaScript reserved words being used as a name.
>   The JavaScript specification reserves a number of words which are
>   currently not used as JavaScript keywords. Using those words as
>   identifiers may result in broken code if later versions of JavaScript
>   use them as keywords.

An example piece of code where this error happens due to the return type:

[image: Error example]

Why can't the `this` keyword be a type? Am I perhaps using an old TypeScript compiler or is it a mistake in the typing?

---

**Edit:**
To get rid of the errors I've just replaced all these `this` types with the type of the containing class or interface. For example, the errors in the given example are fixed by changing it to this:

```
export interface EventEmitter {
    addListener(event: string, listener: Function): EventEmitter;
    ...
}
```

Although, this is not a solution to the actual problem.

Comment: This looks like a bug in WebStorm.

Comment: I think SLaks is right. It works fine for me in Atom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you use old version of WebStorm. WebStorm supports 'this' type starting from v11.0.3.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I perhaps using an old TypeScript compiler ... ?

Yes, upgrade to at least TS 1.7 to get [polymorphic this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910) support.

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles just fine in the typescript playground:

```
export interface E
{
    b(): this;
}

class A implements E
{
    public b(): any
    {
        return 123;
    }   
}

let a = new A();
console.log(a.b());
```

And according to [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#42-the-this-keyword) 'this' will be interpreted as 'any'. 
So most likely there is something with webstorm.

Comment: It's a [polymorphic this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910). It won't be interpreted as `any`.

Comment: Can you please clarify this to me. Logically I also initially thought that this should be pointing to the owner type. But then I had trouble implementing interface in my sample. If I change to 'public b(): E' or 'public b(): A' it will not compile. The only thing that worked was 'any'. How in correct way to implement such interface?

Comment: it helps with [this scenario](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=export%20interface%20E%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20b()%3A%20this%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20A%20implements%20E%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20b()%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0A%09%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0Alet%20thisWillBeTypedAsB%20%3D%20b.b()%3B). If you explicitly typed it, it should be: `b(): this { ... }`